# How to solve a nonlinear system in Matlab without saving a function

Tags: matlab, systems-of-equations

Peace be upon you,

I have a system of equations to be solved. I know that I can solve my system in Matlab like this:

```
function F = myfun(x)
F = [2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
    -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];
```

and save it as "myfun.m" and then in command line I write

```
x0 = [-5; -5];
[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun,x0)
```

But I would like to know how I can do this without defining a function. Because I am using Matlab command line via a proxy provided from another software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by defining an [inline anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
fsolve(@(x) [2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1)); -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))],
      [-5; -5])
```

will do exactly what you want, in a single line that can be evaluated in the interactive prompt.